# MVC htaccess rewrite - hide index

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a basic MVC structure with a restful uri design of:

```
mysite.com/appdir/:index/:controller/:action/
```

and I want to hide the index route parameter so my uri looks like:

```
mysite.com/appdir/:controller/:action/
```

My basic folder structure is:

```
appdir/
  app/
    -->Controller/
    -->Model/
    -->View/
  config/
  library/
  public/
    -->.htaccess
    -->index.php
  .htaccess
  index.php
```

appdir/.htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    public/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) public/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

appdir/public/.htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [PT,L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 index.php
</IfModule>
```

I can't seem to hide the index, I've tried a number of rewrite rules and nothing seems to work.  With CodeIgniter, I can usually add `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]` and problem solved however I've been working on this for 3 hours with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, request path allways starts with /
so first rules should be written like this

RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^/(.*)$    public/$1    [L]

Then I guess in the public dir's htaccess you should use

RewriteBase /public

And finally - why not just set public as DocumentRoot of the webserver
and put all the rules to the single file? in your setup appdir/index.php is never accessible.

Comment: The URL to match in a RewriteRule needs to start with a `/` when you're in `<VirtualHost>` (per-server) context. In `.htaccess` files (Per-directory) context, the URL must *not* start with a `/`.